# Can't see revision history for returned migrations

Tags: bug, migration, revisions-list, migration-rejection

When a migration is rejected after a post is migrated, the post migrates back to the original site.

Normally with migrations you can see the revision history of the migrated post (to give attribution to the editors under CC-BY-SA), but when a post is migrated away and subsequently "returned", one can't see the revision history on the site it was originally migrated to; the page 404's.

I can see this behaviour with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68673949/need-recommendations-for-image-processing-software-for-short-video-clips), which was migrated from Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange to Stack Overflow, then back again, where the links in the top notice and revisions page 404 for me:

[image: Post returned-migration banner above post-closure banner with "returned" link circled]

[image: Post timeline page with "revisions" link in migration even circled]

[image: Electronics.SE 404 page]

Comment: So, I *thought*, after digging a little, that this was just a result of the Electronics.SE post having been [subsequently deleted](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/580433/), and that might still be related, but revision histories of posts that are migrated away do seem to normally be accessible post-deletion. [Here's an example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/223009/revisions) on MSE, the post was migrated to MSO and then deleted, but the revision history is still public, even to logged-out users.

Comment: The real problem, then, seems that instead of providing an explanation that the post was deleted for X reason, a link to the revision history will just 404.